# extract text from pdf file object in python

Tags: python, file, pdf

can we extract text from pdf file object collected from request for example

```
f = request.FILES.get('file', None)
```

So from `f` can we extract text of the document as we get text content from text file object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library called textract

http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It supports a lot of formats including PDF

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I want to extract text from file object not file.